# What rule will make my Firebase storage bucket accessible only to my Firebase Function in the same project?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

My file upload to a Cloud Storage bucket only happen from the Firebase console.  What Cloud Storage rule would allow only my Firebase function in the same project to read/write to the bucket?

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
       ???
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Functions run with administrative access to the project they're a part of. This means you can simply give no regular users access to the bucket, as Cloud Functions bypasses your rules anyway.

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start#sample-rules):

> ```
> // Access to files through Firebase Storage is completely disallowed.
> // Files may still be accessible through Google App Engine or GCS APIs.
> service firebase.storage {
>   match /b/{bucket}/o {
>     match /{allPaths=**} {
>       allow read, write: if false;
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

Your access from Cloud Functions falls under the "GCS APIs" in the comments above.